# Translating Captcha Freeform Pro

Tags: solspace-freeform, transcribe, captcha

we are using Freeform Pro and Transcribe to build forms and translate content.

Using the composer tag, is there a way for the CAPTCHA label 'Please enter the word you see in the image below' to be translated.

Is there a way to break the captcha out of the tag and translate?

We are using the tag below to bring in the code:

```
{exp:freeform:composer
  form_name="general_product_enquiry"
  return="{segment_1}/{segment_2}/{segment_3}/thank_you"
  parse="inward"
}
```

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well there are two simple ways to do that:

1)

- Go to `system\expressionengine\third_party\freeform\language\english\freeform_lang.php`
- Search for the array `captcha_input_instructions` and change the text to yours.

2)

Use JQuery to change the text from Label:

Ex:

```
{if segment_1 == 'de'}
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.captcha_label').text('DE text goes here!')
    });
</script>
{/if}
```

Comment: Thanks - I went for the JS option in the end as I only had a few languages to handle so suited just fine. Merry Christmas.